# Postgres Function on PostGIS does not return the same rows with SQL Queries

Tags: postgresql

I have a db of city geocode value like `lat: 55.8652, lon: -4.2514`.
When I run the SQL on Supabase SQL Editor, then I get the values that I want.

```
SELECT *
FROM education
WHERE ST_Distance (education.loc, ST_SetSRID (ST_MakePoint ( -4.2514, 55.8652), 4326)) <= 8000
order by
ST_Distance (
education.loc,
ST_SetSRID (ST_MakePoint ( -4.2514, 55.8652), 4326)
)
LIMIT 10;
```

However, as soon as I try to use a function to call it on my Flutter App, it never returns the value that I want. It was just returning the 10 rows from the top of my education table.

```
create
or replace function "education" ( lat float, lon float) returns setof education language sql as $$
SELECT *
FROM education
WHERE ST_Distance (education.loc, ST_SetSRID (ST_MakePoint (lon, lat), 4326)) <= 8000
order by
ST_Distance (
education.loc,
ST_SetSRID (ST_MakePoint (lon, lat), 4326)
)
LIMIT 10;
$$;
```

I checked the function and it looks like `lat` and `lon`'s types are set to `double precision`. I think this is the problem. How can I use `lat: 55.8652, lon: -4.2514` this format on Postgres Function? I'd tried to set them as numeric and then add `::float` to `ST_MakePoint`. But, it does not work and I am quite lost right now!

--- changes

```
  const a = await supabase.rpc("education_search", {
    page: 0,
    lat: 55.8652,
    lon: -4.2514,
  });

  console.log(a);
```

Comment: How did you invoke the function?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to use the same name "education" for table and function. Everything works if you get the syntax right, but you're inviting errors of the kind you are here for. For the record, `float`, `float8`, and `double precision` are aliases for the same type in Postgres, and certainly not the problem here.

Comment: I changed the name to `education_search`. And still it just returns the first 10 rows of my table.

Answer (score 0):

When using latitude and longitude values in your PostgreSQL function, you can fix problems with data types and precision by making these adjustments.

Preserve accuracy for latitude and longitude values by converting the data types of the lat and lon parameters in your PostgreSQL function to numeric.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "education" (lat numeric, lon numeric) RETURNS SETOF education LANGUAGE SQL AS $$
-- Rest of your function code
$$;
```

Make sure to use.toDouble() to pass the latitude and longitude values as double precision to match the parameter types of your PostgreSQL function when using the PostgreSQL function from your Flutter app. This keeps geographic calculations as precise as possible.

```
const a = await supabase.rpc("education_search", {
  page: 0,
  lat: 55.8652.toDouble(),
  lon: -4.2514.toDouble(),
});

console.log(a);
```

Hope it works :)

Comment: does not work :/

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a function with 3 parameters (page, lat, lon) but the function you have shown expects two only. It can't work.

--> remove the `page` parameter.

While there, it is better to use `st_dwithin` in the `where` clause as it can make use of a spatial index.

Make sure that your `education.loc` is a geography, not a geometry, else the distance check is done in degrees, not meters, and the distance ordering will be worth close to nothing.

Comment: I'd added page later. So, it did not have that error. Basically, I use the same coordinates on SQL Editor and function call. On SQL Editor, it returned the correct rows but on a function call, it keeps giving me the same row no matter the coordinates.